# How does a user know what attributes are private or public?

Tags: python, attributes

Apologies if this question is dumb, but I'm just getting to grips with OOP.

Attributes of a class can be made semi-private by prefixing it with a single underscore. But how does a user actually know what the attributes are, if they're not included in the documentation, without looking at the code?

Comment: `vars(some_object)`? Or `dir(some_object)`? In the interactive console you can also use `help(some_object)` and it will show all attributes and methods with their docstrings.

Comment: @Bakuriu But dpesn't `help()` only list the methods, not the attributes?

Comment: There is no difference between attributes and methods in Python. If you have *an instance* of an object and call `help` on it all attributes and methods will be shown. If you call `help` *on the class*, then (instance) attributes are not part of the class and hence aren't shown.  By the way: I don't see any difference with respect to other languages. If you have a (e.g.) Java program that: 1) doesn't provide documentation and 2) You don't want to look at the code then you don't have *any* way to get a list of the methods or attributes of the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python is generally based on convention rather than hard-enforced rules, so _blah is understood by programmer and reader to be something internal to the working of the class, and not for accessing directly when you call the class or one of its instances.

Having said that, the dir() function will bare all if you ask it:

```
dir(myinstance)
```

or

```
dir(myclass)
```

if you want to see any inline documentation, you can say:

```
help(myinstance.mymethod)
```